# How to get an Arraylist's name Java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I would like to get the name of a given `ArrayList` in java.

For example:

```
Arraylist<Arraylist> listOfArrays

Arraylist<String> stringListOne (lets say this has 3 elements)
Arraylist<String> stringListTwo (this one too)

listOfArrays.add(stringlistOne);
listOfArrays.add(stringlistTwo);
```

If I want to do the following, `String listName = listOfArrays.get(1)`... It just gives me the `List` `stringlistTwo`.

But I need the list's name itself, `"stringlistTwo"`, altough I didn't find any method for it.

Is it possible?

Or I need to create a `List` with the `ArrayList`s' names?

Comment: There's no way to do that in java.  You can have as many variables as you like pointing to a single object in memory.  How would it know which variable name to give you?  If you need to store associated data with a list, you could use a `Map<String, List<String>>` or create a wrapper object, etc.

Comment: What are you trying to **do** with the name? As azurefrog told you that's not possible as you describe it.

Comment: you can use a Map to map ArrayList<String> with the name

Comment: As @azurefrog said, this cannot be done.  However, I'm curious to know *why* you want to do this.  It's very possible that this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), in which case there's almost certainly a more reasonable way to accomplish whatever your ultimate goal is.

Comment: Variable names are Information that is usually only interesting while devleoping and looking at source code. During Runtime you shouldn't realy need to know any of that information. If you somehow do think you need that information, then that does sound like bad design and a typical [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I would like to make a listview activity in android, what always shows the needed list what the user selected. I want to save the lists to their own sharedpreferences folder, and get their name for the title of the activity.

Comment: @Lety Good idea, thanks!

Comment: @Jordan see above.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting downvoted. The answer to your question is "no", but it's a clear, well stated question, and you've clearly put thought into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the solutions already proposed, if you are flexible to use custom class, you can create a metadata class and add that to your list like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> StringListOne = new ArrayList<>();
    // add values
    List<String> StringListTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    // add values

    List<ListMetadata> metadataList = new ArrayList<>();
    metadataList.add(new ListMetadata("StringListOne", StringListOne));
    metadataList.add(new ListMetadata("StringListTwo", StringListTwo));

    // get first list name
    String firstListName = metadataList.get(0).getName();

    // get list of all names
    List<String> names = metadataList.stream().map(ListMetadata::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

static class ListMetadata {
    String name;
    List<String> value;

    public ListMetadata(String name, List<String> value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Advantages with this approach:

1. You can add more meta information in the future. For example `count` of items in the list.
2. Using `List` so your insertion order is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Maps allow you to identify values by a hashable key, such as a name string. Popular implementations include [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). The former is generally faster, while the latter is sorted:

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists = new HashMap<>();

Arraylist<String> stringListOne (lets say this has 3 elements)
Arraylist<String> stringListTwo (this one too)

mapOfLists.put("StringListOne", stringListOne);
mapOfLists.put("StringListTwo", stringListTwo);
```

You can now access your lists by name:

```
List<String> someList = mapOfLists.get("StringListTwo");
```

This is not exactly what you have in your example though. It is not advisable to use mutable objects for keys, since the hash value is likely to change. Instead, you may want to just map indices to names. You don't strictly need a `Map` object for this, since a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) can be interpreted as a special case that maps contiguous non-negative integers to values. The easiest solution may be to create a list of names parallel to `listOfArrays`:

```
List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
listOfNames.add("StringListOne");
listOfNames.add("StringListTwo");
```

Now you can do

```
String nameOfFirstList = listOfNames.get(0);
```

Comment: I think I will roll with this. Thank you!